# Code structure of third party framework

Tags: c#, mvc, rest, api, solid

Is an API always returning 200 OK, an issue?

Answer (score 3):

**200 OK**

Always returning "200 OK" is a terrible practice. It really kills anyone trying to write a client against the API. REST client frameworks rely on accurate status codes and will break if they receive "200 OK" even when it's not OK. The author of the REST client will have to jump through hoops to make it work correctly.

As a case study, I was recently tasked to integrate with a REST API using Java and the Spring Framework. Now, Spring is a very common and mature framework, I've practically always been able to rely on it. However, this time it would not authenticate with the REST endpoint no matter what I did, and I had even implemented very similar clients -- with authentication -- in the past.

After quite some time of debugging and checking my code and configuration, I realized the REST API is returning "403 Forbidden" when it wanted me to authenticate, whereas the correct code would've been "401 Unauthorized"! Spring would've sent the HTTP basic authentication code automatically as a response to 401, but not to 403, so I had to create a bunch of extra code to handle the situation.

This time it at least returned an error code, but returning "200 OK" would've broken the system at least equally badly. This is because the response JSON object is supposed to be automatically deserialized into an object. If the status is "200 OK" but the content is not the expected kind of JSON object (or a JSON object at all!), well, you can see there's going to be trouble.